# I am trying to place multiple divs inside on one div

Tags: html, css, width, center

I'm new to HTML and CSS. I am trying to place a div with a wide image at the top center of the page and have another div with an image to the left of the wide image, but I need it to always be center between the left side of the image and the edge of the page.

I currently have the center div...

```
{
width: auto;
height: auto;
margin: 0 auto;
padding: 10px;
position: relative;
border: 1px solid black;
width: 950px;}
```

I now need the other image to always be center between the left side of the image and the edge of the page.

[image: position of divs]

Comment: Guess you might need to use flexboxes.

Comment: I had never used Flexboxes before. They have done pretty much exactly what I needed to do. The only problem i have now is on IE and Chome, when the page resolution is small, the content overlap. On Firefox its fine

Answer (score 1):

Having a div within a div is simple you just need to have a separate Id for each of them which I will show you how to do.

```
 <head>
       <style type="text/css>
             div#div1
                 {
                     width:100%; //This is your big div for example
                 {

              div#div2
                 {
                     width:30%; //This is your big div for example
                     float: left; //this makes the div stick to the left side of the div. But the code should look something like this.
                 {
       </style>

 </head>
<body>
    <div id="div1">       
          <div id="div2">


          </div>
    </div>
</body>
```